# BlueCove failed to open connection [10064] - BT Module BT122

Tags: java, windows, bluetooth, bluecove

We are working with BlueCove (Java Bluetooth library) for years now without any issue. Now, we have a successor of the current BT-Module, which is BT122 (Silabs) and it starts making fun with me.

It works with a regular BT-Virtual-Com-Connection in combination with a terminal-tool e.g. teraterm.

BUT: BlueCove the library used so far won't work any more. It cancels the connection with the below displayed window-messages.

On calling `Connector.open(url)` I always get

```
[BLUECOVE] will throw exception javax/bluetooth/BluetoothConnectionException(Failed to connect; [10064] A socket operation failed because the destination host was down.)
```

The counterpart of the connection, which is the BT-Dongle BT122 says the following messages, which basically means the connection is closed as well.

```
Waiting for connection...
uart_rx() - data_length: 4  A0090700
uart_rx() - data_length: 9  D051F4ACC670000207
uart_rx() - data_length: 4  A0020F03
uart_rx() - data_length: 2  0207
uart_tx() - data_length: 5  20010F0507
uart_rx() - data_length: 4  A0070400
uart_rx() - data_length: 7  03D051F4ACC670
SPP connection from 70:c6:ac:f4:51:d0 at endpoint 3
uart_rx() - data_length: 4  A0150702
uart_rx() - data_length: 21  039202000000D051F4ACC670010001010000000005
uart_rx() - data_length: 4  A0070B02
uart_rx() - data_length: 7  03200000000007
Endpoint status:7 0
uart_rx() - data_length: 4  A0020401
uart_rx() - data_length: 2  038D
uart_rx() - data_length: 4  A0030B03
uart_rx() - data_length: 3  130203
Closing endpoint:3
uart_tx() - data_length: 5  20010B0203
uart_rx() - data_length: 4  A0070B02
uart_rx() - data_length: 7  03200000000015
Endpoint status:15 0
uart_rx() - data_length: 4  201A0F05
uart_rx() - data_length: 26  0000D051F4ACC67010105058E961DA4DA891F130C4F9FFA994B8
Bonding from 70:c6:ac:f4:51:d0 succesful
uart_rx() - data_length: 4  20030B02
uart_rx() - data_length: 3  000003
rsp_endpoint_close.result == 0 -FINISHED-
uart_rx() - data_length: 4
```

What remedies can I try for such a case?